# Firefox shows Chinese/strange encoding characters on pages

Tags: firefox, encoding, unicode

[image]

This happens on Google Accounts like Gmail, Twitter.. a few other SSL pages and some non SSL pages. I have tried those pages on Chrome and they work fine.

I have tried following the View > Character encoding suggestion [here](https://superuser.com/questions/23777/firefox-displays-garbage-characters-in-lieu-of-web-page) but not working. Removed all addons, tried without addons, re-installed FF, restarted, cleared cache of entire PC completely.. still some pages show this.

Comment: That's nothing to do with character encoding -- it rather looks like a missing mime type declaration (and a binary being displayed). What are the first few characters (which are cut-off in your screenshot)? They could indicate the real file type. Another possibility might be something going wrong with SSL, and you're looking at the still encrypted content.

Comment: SSL I doubt it as it works fine for Chrome and other browsers and other Firefox users within my offices: First few characters are not cut, off. The first few characters ARE IN FACT the question mark diamonds: ��}k��u����V4

Comment: You could try to connect to a non-SSL site exhibiting the problem, and trace the connection using [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/). That should give you access to the raw bytes exchanged between your computer and that site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this issue. I just downgraded to Firefox 7.

Answer (score 3):

I have the same problem.

1. In the address bar, type: `about:config`
2. Promise to be careful
3. Type in the filter bar: `encoding`
4. Double click on the 'value' column of `network.http.accept-encoding`.
5. Change the 'string value' from gzip, deflate to `true`.

You can also try making sure the proxy is set to `Auto` in

> Tools > Options > Advanced > Network > Connection >  Settings > No Proxy

I still get problems with Google and Gmail though. Same thing

Comment: This does not work. I saw this and a few other similar solutions from Firefox..

Answer (score 3):

Some suggestions which are more in the nature of tests, to better understand the problem:

1. In the case that the website use fonts that you do not have installed or Firefox cannot read properly:
   In `Tools>Options>Content`
   locate the Advanced button under "Fonts & Colours"
   and uncheck "Allow pages to choose their own fonts"
2. Try again in `View->Character Encoding`, but choose other encoding such the two Western.
3. As this can be a problem with the fonts on your computer,
   please give us the address of a page that shows this problem in consistent manner,
   so we can analyze which character encoding it uses.

It would also help to know what is your operating system, its language, and which other language packs you have installed.

[EDIT]

I have analyzed your posted page, and I must remark that I have never seen a page garbled to that degree.
The page has no resemblance at all to the Google Account page - not even the slightest.
Everything is wrong, starting with the header and continuing to the body.
The body itself is a garbage-can of strange characters inter-spaced with end-of-lines
(carriage-return/line-feed). The character-encoding is not identifiable - not ansi/utf8/utf16.
Firefox auto-detect did not succeed any better in identifying it.

**Conclusion:** Some proxy software between you and google.com is garbling your pages.

If you have any sort of proxy software installed, I suggest to uninstall it.
If you use any DNS provider either than your ISP, return to that of the ISP, or try [Google DNS](https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/docs/using).

Otherwise, to test, you could boot in "Safe mode with Network" and see if the problem disappears.
If it does disappear, then some installed product is responsible, which you need to find out
(see [autoruns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx)).

If the problem remains, then the only further suggestions I can make are :

- Use Windows Update to ensure that your system is fully patched (including optional updates)
- Check for virus infection using several well-known anti-virus products
- Use the [System File Checker](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/1538-sfc-scannow-command-system-file-checker.html) to verify system integrity
- Verify the web parameters of your PC and router, especially concerning DNS
- Get in touch with your ISP's Support

Comment: https://accounts.google.com - this redirects to https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?passive=1209600&continue=https%3A%2F%2Faccounts.google.com%2FManageAccount&followup=https%3A%2F%2Faccounts.google.com%2FManageAccount - the Firefox is 13.0.1 and is Windows Home 64bit - In English; language packs loads - but all default and do not use them.

I tried your suggestions but still nothing.

Comment: Strange, this page is quite innocently encoded in utf-8 and uses the arial font. No way that anything could go wrong with arial without greatly lousing up you computer. Does [this page](http://hell.meiert.org/core/html/helvetica-arial.html) display correctly (same text 3 times) ?

Comment: That page works perfectly.

Comment: Could you do SaveAs to the [google account page](https://accounts.google.com/) while it's full of diamonds in complete webpage format and post the whole thing (maybe zipped?) for us somewhere.

Comment: http://www.filefactory.com/file/5h6qf3ghbdqv/n/Google_zip

Comment: I'm not sure whether “Complete webpage format” is a good choice here: as FF will rewrite that page to change image links, it might also decide to rewrite its encoding. So I'd rather try "HTML only".

Comment: I just upgraded Firefox to 14 and all Google sites are failing. Google search - I cannot do anything on Google on Firefox.

Comment: Try to uninstall Firefox, delete all folders (search "Firefox" in system disk for data in "C:\Program Files" and in "C:\Users"), then reinstall Firefox. If this doesn't fix the problem, try using another computer in your house thru same line - this will tell you whether the problem is in your computer or with your ISP (or router).